# Error: No named parameter with the name 'onPressed'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

So, i'm trying to create an app in flutter and cannot work my way around the syntax code. The error is that it is not able to recognise onPressed. Ps new to flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to call onPressed on a Center widget which has no onPressed parameter.

Try calling onPressed on a RaisedButton or any other widget that has an onPressed parameter instead:

```
RaisedButton(
onPressed: //Your function here,
),
```